# Intellij IDEA: changelist shows wrong changes / modify changelist manually?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, intellij-14, changelist

I have a problem with my Intellij IDEA. The changelist shows that I have locally deleted a file X.java. In fact, the file is not deleted, neither locally nor on the SVN server. It exists (both SVN and locally) and its even possible to access this file with the IDEA editor (ctrl + n -> shows the file etc). I am using Win 7 with Intellij IDEA 14.

So here is my problem: IDEA shows in the changes window that file x.java was locally deleted and I just can't convince IDEA that it is not deleted...

Here is what I tried so far:

- SVN revert -> no effect
- SVN cleanup -> no effect
- Invalidate caches and restart -> no effect
- manually delete caches folder -> no effect
- Exclude src folder and include it again (in project settings) -> no effect

Does anyone know where IDEA stores the changelist and is it possible to modify this changelist? Or even delete it so it has to be build again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the file from SVN and adding it again solved the problem. Unfortunately it is still unclear to me why IDEA showed this file as locally deleted.